# How can I reduce VM size in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I had a common question here, I using Virtual Box to create virtual machine, the situation is I need to reduce the VM size, as it grow when there is data moved into the VM, and after the data has been clear out, the VM size never reduce.

How can I reduce the unnecessary size?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: anyone? please help

Comment: *sigh*  Honestly, your question doesn't provide enough detail for an answer, is probably off-topic for the site, and you should be able to find your answer on Google anyway, but... "you inspire terrible pity," so why not.  Got nothing better to do while this database is crunching along anyway.  I'll put something up for you in a little bit here...

Comment: Full instruction: https://www.howtogeek.com/312883/how-to-shrink-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-and-free-up-disk-space/

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [VBoxManage modifyhd](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi)

I think this command will do what you want:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd diskname.vdi --compact
```

This command will only be effective on VDI images.

> With the --compact option, can be used to compact disk images, i.e. remove blocks that only contains zeroes. This will shrink a dynamically allocated image again; it will reduce the physical size of the image without affecting the logical size of the virtual disk. Compaction works both for base images and for diff images created as part of a snapshot.

Note:

> For this operation to be effective, it is required that free space in the guest system first be zeroed out using a suitable software tool. For Windows guests, you can use the sdelete tool provided by Microsoft. Execute sdelete -z in the guest to zero the free disk space before compressing the virtual disk image. For Linux, use the zerofree utility which supports ext2/ext3 filesystems.